# Need to sort the output of mongo aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I have successfully created the mongo aggregate function but am stuck in how to sort the output data. The query is this:

```
db.abc.aggregate (
    [
        {
            $match: {field1: "26695118", field2: "STATE_A"} 
        }, 
        {
            $group: { 
                "_id": { "deviceId": "$deviceId", "dateOfRecord": "$dateOfRecord" }, 
                sum : { $sum: "$durationSeconds" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

This works fine. But what I want is that the result to show deviceId1 first with all the dates of deviceId1 in an ascending order, followed by deviceId2 with its dates in ascending order and so on, similar to what we would have in a SQL query with

```
SELECT ... order by deviceId, dateOfRecord
```

I tried the following

```
db.abc.aggregate (
    [
        {
            $match: {field1: "26695118", field2: "STATE_A"} 
        }, 
        {
            $group: { 
                "_id": { "deviceId": "$deviceId", "dateOfRecord": "$dateOfRecord" }, 
                sum : { $sum: "$durationSeconds" }
            }
        },
        {$sort : {field1: 1, field2: 1}}
    ]
)
```

But it does not work. What am I missing here. Note that I do not want the SUM to be sorted, but the fields, only.

Sample Output

```
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647302400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(65435) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f9e88f89-a382-4812-92a7-f35891db9b71", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1650931200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(33133) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "444e8e69-e947-4b23-ba59-16246f65f862", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647043200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(39815) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "36d5ba54-4ddc-47f0-9d89-cbc1896d7646", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647993600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(47701) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "fc64d29f-7892-47fb-adc7-e166b200f9cc", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1651363200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(46322) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f8903ccd-cb5c-4e6b-8e54-a65d0624db15", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648166400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(39475) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "36d5ba54-4ddc-47f0-9d89-cbc1896d7646", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1653696000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(39891) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "c7976720-9604-4a51-82a6-f7d81911ebff", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646697600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(42318) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "d2b05da6-2e3c-46b4-b921-7b80b7adefac", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1653177600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(31199) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "57411800-d707-4efb-8f05-c762821c3635", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1654473600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(42256) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "d2b05da6-2e3c-46b4-b921-7b80b7adefac", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1650758400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(46711) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "7a5a843a-c2f9-4c8e-88b7-2244000e6431", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1650326400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(30202) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "3cb718d1-bff2-4d8d-9304-4578652c165e", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652572800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(41954) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "ee827f4e-1350-49f0-a94e-8456eb4a928d", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646092800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(32713) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "d2b05da6-2e3c-46b4-b921-7b80b7adefac", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1651363200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(44728) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "7a5a843a-c2f9-4c8e-88b7-2244000e6431", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646438400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(27949) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f8903ccd-cb5c-4e6b-8e54-a65d0624db15", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648771200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(29658) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "afe370bf-cc0e-4a27-8abf-ae7427f8258a", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652313600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(56197) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f8903ccd-cb5c-4e6b-8e54-a65d0624db15", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1653350400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(40372) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "3cb718d1-bff2-4d8d-9304-4578652c165e", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652745600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(54362) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "5cde3550-bc0e-4aac-b91d-9b44d57469d9", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1653264000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(37828) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "1fda1716-d22a-4dfc-b01d-a4dd33e624d5", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647043200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(67989) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "5cde3550-bc0e-4aac-b91d-9b44d57469d9", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1655164800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(43987) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "30580c8a-032f-4ed4-a095-85b0198e5497", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1651190400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(26735) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "3cb718d1-bff2-4d8d-9304-4578652c165e", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649116800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(61896) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652227200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(69616) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "36d5ba54-4ddc-47f0-9d89-cbc1896d7646", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1650153600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(32274) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "1fda1716-d22a-4dfc-b01d-a4dd33e624d5", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647734400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(28253) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "57411800-d707-4efb-8f05-c762821c3635", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1651276800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(54491) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "e4415df0-d3ce-41e3-8682-a630905a318f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1654128000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(42286) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f9e88f89-a382-4812-92a7-f35891db9b71", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648684800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(34727) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1654992000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(45815) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f9e88f89-a382-4812-92a7-f35891db9b71", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646179200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(58156) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1654819200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(51607) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "67cc0f4f-c448-44dd-97b2-0871ed185945", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646697600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(70972) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "36d5ba54-4ddc-47f0-9d89-cbc1896d7646", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648252800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(43972) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "1fda1716-d22a-4dfc-b01d-a4dd33e624d5", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648598400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(37396) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "5cde3550-bc0e-4aac-b91d-9b44d57469d9", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649376000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(37077) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f8903ccd-cb5c-4e6b-8e54-a65d0624db15", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647734400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(61518) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "67cc0f4f-c448-44dd-97b2-0871ed185945", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1653004800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(35342) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "33781349-bcfe-49cf-88b3-a98021f5f32f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648425600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(35186) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "afe370bf-cc0e-4a27-8abf-ae7427f8258a", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652400000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(62764) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "33781349-bcfe-49cf-88b3-a98021f5f32f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1654905600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(50736) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "57411800-d707-4efb-8f05-c762821c3635", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652486400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(1808) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "444e8e69-e947-4b23-ba59-16246f65f862", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646352000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(52370) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652400000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(44108) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "7a5a843a-c2f9-4c8e-88b7-2244000e6431", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647993600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(62388) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648684800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(56090) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "36d5ba54-4ddc-47f0-9d89-cbc1896d7646", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1653868800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(54164) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "67cc0f4f-c448-44dd-97b2-0871ed185945", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649030400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(17926) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "7a5a843a-c2f9-4c8e-88b7-2244000e6431", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649462400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(35619) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "afe370bf-cc0e-4a27-8abf-ae7427f8258a", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648339200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(52319) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "afe370bf-cc0e-4a27-8abf-ae7427f8258a", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648512000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(33714) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "33781349-bcfe-49cf-88b3-a98021f5f32f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652313600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(40943) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649808000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(41417) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "5cde3550-bc0e-4aac-b91d-9b44d57469d9", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647043200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(38563) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "d2b05da6-2e3c-46b4-b921-7b80b7adefac", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1655078400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(39187) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "67cc0f4f-c448-44dd-97b2-0871ed185945", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1655164800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(33781) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "5cde3550-bc0e-4aac-b91d-9b44d57469d9", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1650931200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(36645) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "3cb718d1-bff2-4d8d-9304-4578652c165e", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648771200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(54322) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "7a5a843a-c2f9-4c8e-88b7-2244000e6431", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648166400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(49741) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "444e8e69-e947-4b23-ba59-16246f65f862", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1648857600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(36267) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "44c82f94-09bd-424c-9817-d5baf91af35c", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649635200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(54791) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "33781349-bcfe-49cf-88b3-a98021f5f32f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646611200000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(35888) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "f9e88f89-a382-4812-92a7-f35891db9b71", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649289600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(36481) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "30580c8a-032f-4ed4-a095-85b0198e5497", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1652140800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(21554) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "33781349-bcfe-49cf-88b3-a98021f5f32f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647993600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(53600) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "c7976720-9604-4a51-82a6-f7d81911ebff", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1654300800000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(32368) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "30580c8a-032f-4ed4-a095-85b0198e5497", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1651536000000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(43612) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "33781349-bcfe-49cf-88b3-a98021f5f32f", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1646265600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(40167) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "67cc0f4f-c448-44dd-97b2-0871ed185945", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1647129600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(52726) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "67cc0f4f-c448-44dd-97b2-0871ed185945", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1651190400000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(43916) }
{ "_id" : { "deviceId" : "c7976720-9604-4a51-82a6-f7d81911ebff", "dateOfRecord" : NumberLong("1649721600000") }, "sum" : NumberLong(53020) }
```

Comment: afte group you will have only 2 fields `_id` and `sum`, i think you want to sort by `_id.deviceId` and `_id.dateOfRecord`

Comment: Cool .. thanx a ton. This is the one that worked for me. ```{$sort : {"_id.deviceId": 1, "_id.dateOfRecord": 1}}```

Answer (score 0):

Complete query for sorting is as follows (Thanks again to Takis for the help):

```
db.abc.aggregate (
    [
        {
            $match: {field1: "26695118", field2: "STATE_A"} 
        }, 
        {
            $group: { 
                "_id": { "deviceId": "$deviceId", "dateOfRecord": "$dateOfRecord" }, 
                sum : { $sum: "$durationSeconds" }
            }
        },
        {$sort : {"_id.deviceId": 1, "_id.dateOfRecord": 1}}
    ]
)
```